# Is it possible to get GTA San Andreas on PS3 if I already own it on Google Play?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I've bought GTA: San Andreas on the Google Play Store, and I want to get it on PS3.

Is it possible to get it for free if I already own the game on Google Play?

Answer (score 6):

No.  The Playstation Store and Google Play are two different entities and exchanging this kind of information between the two is impossible.

Comment: Additionally, transferring the license isn't an option across platforms.